# How to avoid inter-node traffic in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have the following setup:

- n nodes each with a certain service instance
- n service pods (1 for each node)
- n dynamic IP endpoints (one for each service/node). External client are bonded to a certain instance of the service (one client once set up, should comunicate with one service instance only). **IPs are not available at cluster init.**, but are added later.
- the traffic in question is GRPC.

Do you guys have any idea how to set something like this up in Kubernetes? How do I assign the IPs to work this way?
The idea behind it is that I would like to avoid inter-node traffic redirects? Is there another way to accomplish this within these restrictions?

Bonus if it is fault tolerant if a node goes down.

Here is a schematic to make things a little clearer:

[image]

Case for node 2 going down:

[image]

Edits: added more info to make the question more clear.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy each application on different nodes and if node belonging to a particular application goes down you want to deploy this application on remaining nodes but they should be isolated.. have you tried using [Node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into that, but my issue is how do I set the IPs to the services to work in this way.

Comment: just use `externalTrafficPolicy: external`

Comment: If you remove the constraints that there is exactly one replica per node and that you don't ever want network traffic between nodes, then you're just asking to deploy a new copy of the application with a new LoadBalancer Service for each tenant (repeated `helm install`, for example).  Would that approach work for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze not really, we are not using helm, and this is not a cloud solution :), I was looking at this https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/ for a bare metal LB

Answer (score 1):

If it is HTTP/HTTPS clients, you could set up an [Integress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) in your kubernetes cluster. The [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend) resources defines the http/https routes (rules) from the clients to the services within the cluster.

[image]

Basically, the ingress-managed load balancer will provide a public URL (DNS) or public IP that external clients are bound to.
This can be further improved with combination of [headless service](https://medium.com/@bubu.tripathy/headless-k8s-service-924c689607a7) and routing rules in ingress-managed load balancer.

Comment: It is not HTTP traffic unfortunately. It is GRPC traffic.

Comment: @AlexEfimov gRPC is over HTTP2. So, Ingress controller should support that. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/grpc/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the default available `internalTrafficPolicy` field for services, just in case it is enough for your usecase before diving into complex solutions:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#internal-traffic-policy

Setting it to `local` will make it so all node-local traffic will be routed to node-local endpoints.
One (substantial) caveat is if no local endpoints can be found, traffic is dropped instead of being rerouted to other nodes.

You could also look into Topology Aware Routing, however it is harder to set-up and maintain, necessitating many available endpoints across many zones to be effective:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/topology-aware-routing/#enabling-topology-aware-routing

It does have the advantage of being tolerant to node failures however